# runtime error 1004 you typed an invalid name for a sheet or chart

Tags: excel, vba, import, spreadsheet

I am having a problem renaming a sheet to the original file name that it was imported from. I am suspecting that it has to do with naming convention in the part where I import and target the workbook but running out of ideas.

Once the sheet is imported into the Excel file, that it changes the sheet name to the original Excel file name that it was imported from:

```
Sub ImportSheetsFromFolder()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Prompt user to select folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder Containing Excel Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected. Exiting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Set target workbook (current workbook)
    Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Prompt user for sheet name to import
    sheetName = InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet to import:", "Sheet Name")
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No sheet name provided. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each file in the selected folder
    selectedFile = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While selectedFile <> ""
        ' Open source workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & selectedFile)
        
        ' Check if the sheet exists in the source workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' If the sheet exists, import it into the target workbook and rename
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            ws.Copy After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
             targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = sourceWorkbook.Name & " - " & sheetName
        End If
        
        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        ' Move to the next file
        selectedFile = Dir
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Import complete."
End Sub
```

Comment: There are restrictions on the length of a sheet name, as well as illegal characters. What's the filename? Try changing the sheet name manually to this filename ... you won't be able to but you might be able to see why.

Comment: Yip I just tried changing the sheet name manually and it didnt allow me. I shortened the characters of the file, tried again and a debug points me to this line thats causing an issue: targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = sourceWorkbook.Name & " - " & sheetName

Comment: Your name is still invalid. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-worksheet-3f1f7148-ee83-404d-8ef0-9ff99fbad1f9

Comment: Unrelated: Is there a reason you are using `Sheets` instead of `Worksheets`?

Comment: Thanks, worked. Had to change sheet name